# Linq to Objects - query objects for any non-numeric data

Tags: linq, lambda

I am trying to write some logic to determine if all values of a certain property of an object in a collection are numeric and greater than zero. I can easily write this using ForEach but I'd like to do it using Linq to Object. I tried this:

```
var result = entity.Reports.Any(
    x =>
    x.QuestionBlock == _question.QuestionBlock
    && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Data)) && Int32.TryParse(x.Data, out tempVal) 
    && Int32.Parse(x.Data) > 0);
```

It does not work correctly. I also tried this, hoping that the TryParse() on Int32 will return false the first time it encounter a string that cannot be parsed into an int. But it appears the out param will contain the first value string value that can be parsed into an int.

```
var result = entity.GranteeReportDataModels.Any(
    x =>
    x.QuestionBlock == _question.QuestionBlock
    && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Data)) && Int32.TryParse(x.Data, out tempVal));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if `TryParse` returns false the value of the `out` param is undefined.

Comment: I believe the out parameter is 0 (the default for `int`) if the `TryParse` returns `false`, but this isn't documented. Actually MSDN says that it is returned "uninitialized", but that's not possible, because `out` by definition means that a value must be set before the function returns. Decompiling the method shows that it is infact set to 0 before any work is actually done.

Comment: @BrianBall, I wouldn't write code that relied on that although, it would probably be alright.

Comment: @Jodrell, I completely agree. I would not rely on this behavior, the return value should be checked first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test if "all" values meet a condition, you should use the `All` extension method off `IEnumerable<T>`, not `Any`. I would write it like this:

```
var result = entity.Reports.All(x =>
{
  int result = 0;
  return int.TryParse(x.Data, out result) && result > 0;
});
```

I don't believe you need to test for an null or empty string, because `int.TryPrase` will return false if you pass in a null or empty string.

Comment: +1 for being more concise but, the initialization of `result` to `0` is unnesscessary.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I meant All although Any can be used as well if the logic is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var allDataIsNatural = entity.Reports.All(r =>
     {
         int i;
         if (!int.TryParse(r.Data, out i))
         {
             return false;
         }

         return i > 0;
     });
```

`Any` will return when the first row is `true` but, you clearly say you would like to check them **all**.

Comment: This answer is the same as Brian Balls but as Jodrell said it is not as compact as Brian's Ball. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension which tries to parse a string to `int` and returns a `int?`:

```
public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Then this query works:

```
bool all = entity.Reports.All(x => { 
    if(x.QuestionBlock != _question.QuestionBlockint) 
        return false;
    int? data = x.Data.TryGetInt(); 
    return data.HasValue && data.Value > 0; 
});
```

or more readable (a little bit less efficient):

```
bool all = entityReports
    .All(x => x.Data.TryGetInt().HasValue && x.Data.TryGetInt() > 0 
           && x.QuestionBlock == _question.QuestionBlockint);
```

This approach avoids using a local variable as `out` parameter which is an undocumented behaviour in Linq-To-Objects and might stop working in future. It's also more readable.

Comment: This approach should work and has the added benefits of code being more reusable. But I have not tried it because I am not using Extension method in this particular project. But i will keep it in mind.